# How to make TFS not auto check source control from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

every time I open my Solution in Visual Studio it tries to communicate and validate every file is update to date in source control. I am working on a very large project and was wondering how I could disable it for this Solution? Furthermore is I am curious as to also how to enable it?

Comment: do you open the solution from the source control or from the local .sln file?

Comment: I open the solution from the local .sln file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010:

1)  Go to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment.

2)  In "Source Control Environment Settings," select "Custom" from the drop down.

3)  Uncheck "Get everything when a solution or project is opened."

(This is a global setting.  It is not Solution-specific.)

Comment: I was going to try this but VS doesn't have the "Environment" option.  To fix it another way, I changed my source from "Local" to "Server" (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843300/how-to-disable-auto-check-out-when-i-save-or-edit-file-tfs)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the TFS power tools, assuming you use TFS 2010 then you can download them [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) open up a visual studio command prompt and run the command `tfpt connections` this will bring up a dialogue which will show all of your available TFS servers and Collections.

There are 2 options you can try, firstly uncheck "Automatically connect to server on startup" this should stop VS trying to connect to TFS when you open a solution. If that doesn't work then click on the "+" next to the TFS server and select the collection you are using for source control. Hit the "Edit" button and you should see a checkbox called "Server is Offline" select this and you will no longer be connected to TFS.

To reverse the behaviour use the same tool to togle the values back to their defaults

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019 / 2022 change the following settings

From Toolbar click **Options** menu

Expand **Source Control** option
Click **Environment** sub-menu

Change **Source Control Environment Settings** to ***"Custom"***

Change **Checked-in items** options:

**Saving:** Select ***"Prompt for checkout"*** from dropdown

**Editing:** Select ***"Prompt for checkout"*** from dropdown

Click **OK** button

**Also check the Team Explorer Source Control options**

From **Team Explorer** > **Team Project Collection** > **Source Control**

Under **Workspace Settings** tab > Select ***"Local (recommended)"***

Set **Enable asynchronous checkout in server workspaces** to unticked

Click **OK**