# How to disable auto check out when I save or edit file tfs

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Tell me please how to disable auto checkout in tfs (vs 2013) when I edit or save file?
I can selected "Do nothing" in the Options dialog box, click Source Control, and then click Environment and in the On Edit box, select "Do nothing" and select "Allow checked-in items to be edited", but this doesn`t resolve my problem - files locked after save.
Thank you!

Comment: is your workspace a `Server` workspace? try using a local workspace

Comment: Can you tell me how change server workspace for local?

Comment: @JustTFS: Why would having a local workspace work?

Answer (score 9):

In **Visual Studio 2013**, on the Tools menu, click Options.

In the Options dialog box, click Source Control, and then click Environment.

In the Checked In Items section,
And in Editing- there are three options available.

Select **Do nothing** and click OK

[image: refer this]

Comment: This doesn't work! Now I can not changing any file!
I can select "Allow checked-in items to be edited", but this doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: I selected Do Nothing, but now I can not change any file. All files are Readonly

Comment: check the Allow checked-in items to be edited and see..
And If you are editing such a file that has already checked-in ,you are doing a change so that has to be checked out..

Comment: I checked this... But file locked after save.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but I can't resolve my problem - lock file after save or edit. Can you describe step by step this resolve?

Comment: When I save file, it lock. Do you know how disabled auto lock after save?

Comment: why you need to have different version than the server.It is the normal behavior to checkout the file when editing. (cheked-in file)

Comment: I think you won't be able to edit and save that file inside your solution which connected to the TFS without checking out it. 
Best thing to do is create a branch of your working solution or get a copy of it and do what ever you want. Because you need to detach that file from TFS inorder to do this

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but I think than it isn`t resolve. 
For example two developers or more working on solution and maybe they changing one file, only one developer can change this file?
But I can not see another way: I do unbind, change file than do checkin.

Comment: yes,thats happened with TFS, You can use other tool instead of TFS.
such as tortoisesvn (as the repo browser)  and AnkhSvn as the visual studio extension.
So both of the developers can edit same file at same time. And you have to resolve conflicts if available. Its easy to do the source control

Comment: Thanks, great solution

Answer (score 6):

To change your workspace type.

in the source control window, open the drop down list and select workspaces...
in the editor window change you workspace location from Server to Local.

this will allow your workspace to act like a distributed workspace rather than a traditional TFSVC Server workspace.

[image: workspace type]

Comment: Thanks. Now my workspace is server, but I can change it. This dropdoun disabled