# TFS "GO ONLINE" message while opening visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am using visual studio 2010 and connected to TFS. Every time I try to open the visual studio project it prompts the following message.

```
    ---------------------------                         
    Microsoft Visual Studio                         
    ---------------------------                         
    Go Online                           

    This solution is offline but its associated Team Foundation Server is available.                            

    Would you like to go online with this solution after it has loaded?                         
    ---------------------------                         
    Yes   No   Help                             
    ---------------------------
```

I have tried the following settings in TFS settings as mentioned  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049161/1997066)

- uncheck "Automatically connect to server on startup"
- uncheck  "Server is Offline"

I have also tried  following solutions
[How to make TFS not auto check source control from Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043127/how-to-make-tfs-not-auto-check-source-control-from-visual-studio)

But none of them worked.
How to suppress this message permanently?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to right-click on the solution name right at the top of the Solution Explorer and select the Go Online option. Check the following case for more details:

[How do I get my solution in Visual Studio back online in TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681807/how-do-i-get-my-solution-in-visual-studio-back-online-in-tfs)