# Visual Studio Checks Out Solution and Removes SolutionInfo.cs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

When I right-click on my solution, in solution explorer, and choose Get Latest, Visual Studio gets the latest, but also checks out the solution.

[image]

> Replacing
>   C:\DevTfs2010\Apps\Messaging\Subscribers\AutoTrackerProcessor\Main\AutoTrackerProcessor\SolutionItems\SolutionInfo.cs
>   AutoTrackerProcessor.vssscc, AutoTrackerProcessor.sln have been
>   automatically checked out for editing.

Not only does it check out the solution, but it removes the SolutionInfo.cs file from the solution file. Here is the compare of the solution file:

**Server:**

[image]

**Local:**

[image]

Why would it do this?

Note: Our build process alters the SolutionInfo.cs file, but only that file. It doesn't alter the solution to remove SolutionInfo.cs.

Comment: Do you have the same result (loss of SolutionInfo.cs) when you do "Get Latest" for appropriate folder via the Source Control Explorer?

Comment: No. I did a Get Latest in Source Control Explorer. Then I opened the solution and nothing was checked out. So this only happens when I get latest within the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/12/living-with-team-foundation-server.html) could clarify this question then.

Comment: Thanks, Elena. While that article explains good practices, I'd still be interested in knowing why this is happening.

Comment: Btw, I'm thinking it could be something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085978/how-to-stop-visual-studio-from-always-checking-out-solutions-files. Although that's not the issue with my solution, I'm thinking something along those lines...