# How to stop TFS from checking out after a get latest

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have this issue where if I do a 'get latest' on a file in TFS it straight away prompts to do a check out of the file. It actually greys out the cancel button. I am not sure why getting a latest version should make a file be automatically checked out since I thought the idea was the you only check out a file if you wish to edit it and then check it in again - not just because you have downloaded the latest version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085978/how-to-stop-visual-studio-from-always-checking-out-solutions-files

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)" and "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Are you using Enterprise Library? If yes - there is a known bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/573538/visual-studio-2010-with-tfs-2010-always-checks-out-the-solution-file-when-opening