# GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution , what is it doing in my Visual studio 2012 solution file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, solution

My VS solution file ends in

```
GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
    EnterpriseLibraryConfigurationToolBinariesPath = packages\Unity.2.1.505.2\lib\NET35;packages\Unity.Interception.2.1.505.2\lib\NET35;packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Common.5.0.505.0\lib\NET35;packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.5.0.505.0\lib\NET35;packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Data.5.0.505.0\lib\NET35;packages\EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.5.0.505.0\lib\NET35;packages\EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.5.0.505.0\lib\NET35;packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.5.0.505.0\lib\NET35
EndGlobalSection
```

What is the purpose of it?

TL;DR

In a solution mine VS2012 always wants to check out the solution file but it does nothing with it.
I found a [remedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085978/how-to-stop-visual-studio-from-always-checking-out-solution-files) through removing said rows. It works.
But I wonder if there are any side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing it is fine, it is related to the Enterprise library configuration tool. As you have found while it is there it will always check out the solution file when you open the solution from TFS.

Comment: I understand so far. But I guess the setting is put there for a reason; so something somewhere will change. But what eludes me.

Comment: Do you use the configuration tool or do you manually alter your config files? if it's manual then you will never see any effect from removing that

Comment: How merging for this file works, when a few sides added something and there are a lot of GUIDs ?