# What is the new GlobalSection in a VS2017 15.3 solution file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 15.3.1 and ASP.NET Core 2.0, my solution file now has this at the end:

```
GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
    SolutionGuid = {...a GUID...}
EndGlobalSection
```

What is this, and do I need it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to **Mastering Visual Studio** book the `ExtensibilityGlobals` (and `ExtensibilityAddIns`)  section included for the benefit of add-in authors. `ExtensibilityGlobals` used to store global information about the solution. So it is clearly generated by(or for) some 3rd party tools.

The only discussion about `SolutionGuid`  is [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17041), which is generated by CMake and they advise that you should not touch this property.

Sometimes you can safely delete some properties from this section like [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055015/globalsectionextensibilityglobals-postsolution-what-is-it-doing-in-my-visu).

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link to that book?  I've found a few with that title and am not sure which one you're referencing.

Comment: What do we have to do in resolving theses files in case of merging when a few sides add something and it explodes with our and their GUIDs ?