# Visual Studio 2015 checks solution file out everytime on opening

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, ssis-2016

currently I'm migrating from SQL Server 2012 to 2016. I branched my ETL-projects, then set the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2016 and checked in to TFS. When I open one of these ETL-projects Visual Studio always wants to check out the solution file. Does anyone have a hint what could be the reason and how I can resolve the problem?

Thanks,
Schichti

Hi Andy,

thanks for your answer.

1. Visual Studio Team Foundation Server is selected.
2. I have no extensions installed and unchecked the first three boxes. Problem is still the same.
3. The section "GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals)" doesn't exist in my solution file. Here is the content of my solution file:

   ```
   Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
   # Visual Studio 2010
   Project("{159641D6-6404-4A2A-AE62-294DE0FE8301}") = "ETL_CDW", "ETL_CDW\ETL_CDW.dtproj", "{9000D262-D9FB-4C25-9447-94A58ED86BB6}"
   EndProject
   Global
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
     SccNumberOfProjects = 2
     SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
     SccTeamFoundationServer = http://kerry:8080/tfs/kroschkebi
     SccLocalPath0 = .
     SccProjectUniqueName1 = ETL_CDW\\ETL_CDW.dtproj
     SccProjectName1 = ETL_CDW
     SccLocalPath1 = ETL_CDW
   EndGlobalSection
   GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Development|Default = Development|Default
   EndGlobalSection
   GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
   {9000D262-D9FB-4C25-9447-94A58ED86BB6}.Development|Default.ActiveCfg = Development
   {9000D262-D9FB-4C25-9447-94A58ED86BB6}.Development|Default.Build.0 = Development
   EndGlobalSection
   GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
    HideSolutionNode = FALSE
   EndGlobalSection
   EndGlobal
   ```

   The first two lines are only a comment, right? Because I'm wondering why the format version is 11.00 shouldn't it be 14.00 and why it's still Visual Studio 2010 instead of 2015.

I think the workaround extension wouldn't be helpful as Visual Studio after every undo immediately wants to check out again whether saved or not.

Do you have any other idea what I could try?

Thanks, Schichti

Comment: Have you checked other VS client machines? Is this issue only occur on your client? or all the clients have the same issue?

Comment: I checked it. The VS client machine from my colleague has the same issue.

Comment: Which type of workspace do you use? try to change the workspace type from Server to Local , or Local to Server, then try it again.

Comment: We are using local workspaces. I created a new workspace from type Server but still the same issue. I changed the workspace type from my local workspace to Server but still the same issue also after I changed the type back to Local.

Comment: What about other team projects? All have same issue? If other projects are OK, you can compare and identify the difference between the solutions for troubleshooting.

Comment: All branched Projects have the same issue. I can only compare with the original 2012-Projects. I'll have a look if I can see any differences, which could be resposible for the issue.

Comment: Yeah, just try to compare them. You can also check if the issue also occurs on VS 2017, and try to create a new workspace and remap to a new folder. Then try it again.

Comment: I compared with the orginal 2012-solutions and could not see any difference. I have not the possibility to try it with VS 2017. I created a new workspace but without success. Any other idea?

Comment: Weird, no idea for that, you said "All branched Projects have the same issue", have you tried the new projects, i mean create a new solution, then check if the new solution has the same issue, then branch the solution, then check again for the branched solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below things to narrow down the issue:

1. Check under tools--> options--> Source Control --> Plugin
   selection--> Current Source Control Plugin. Here **Visual Studio
   Team Foundation Server** has to be selected.
2. This problem can also be due to the extensions you may have
   installed, try to open the Solution file after disabling the
   extension (Tools--> Extensions and Updates).
3. Check-out your solution file from source control, then open the
   solution file in a text editor, like Notepad. Find a section named
   "`GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals)`" Delete the entire section:

   `GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
     MyGlobalProperty = AnyValue
   EndGlobalSection`

   Save the solution file in the text editor, check in the solution, close then re-opened it to check if that works for you.

Reference this similar thread: [How to stop Visual Studio from "always" checking out solution files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085978/how-to-stop-visual-studio-from-always-checking-out-solution-files)

If that still not work, as a workaround you can try the extension [Auto Uncheckout for Visual Studio 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KulikovDenis.AutoUncheckoutforVisualStudio2015), it will automatically undo check out file after saving if the file has not been modified.

---

**UPDATE:**

Just try to compare with other projects which don't have the issue and identify the differences between them for further troubleshooting. You can also check if the issue also occurs on VS 2017, and try to create a new workspace and remap to a new folder. Then try it again.